# Nuspec file not copied to deployed folder

Tags: teamcity, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I want my projects nuspec file to be copied over to the published directory. Nuspec file has property set to always copy but still it is not copied to deployed directory. Is there any way to copy it over to the deployed folder as we are updating the version in it and want to see the deployed version from that file.

PLease guide

Answer (score 0):

When a Release is deployed the `Nuspec` file is never copied to the package installation directory as it's considered to me Metadata by Octopus. As an alternative you can use the Deploy.ps1 PowerShell script to write the version number to a file.

```
$version = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Release.Number"]
$version | Out-File "Version.txt"
```